# Same post in two review queues

Tags: support

If a new user posts an answer for an old question,that will be shown under both the [First Posts](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts) and the [Late Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers) review queues, so I can review the same post twice.

Is this by design, or a bug?

Comment: Actual reviewed post sources http://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/32231 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/32230

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, when I see one entry in both categories, and I review one, the other is gone when I revisit the review overview just afterwards.

However, I have experienced being able to review the same post in both categories. This does not happen often: On about 1500 reviews, I can only recall this happening twice.

> Is that by design? or Bug?

Without having direct access to the site's code, it is impossible to know whether it is design or by accident. It can be design (for instance, a question may be re-injected in the queue if it is edited, or it may just be a bug. (Personally, I don't care.)

Comment: It allows me to review both when I open them(First Posts and Late Answers) in different tabs.  :)

Comment: As far as I understood from the now-global meta, it is not designed to be that way, but team decided they can live with tab effect @KrishnaMohan described due to performance issues if they would try to prevent it. Important thing is to get things reviewed at least once. If someone is so eager to review as much as possible to risk reviewing things twice, no real reason to deny him getting review-related badges a tiny bit faster. Simply, work needed is not worth it. **I admit I can't find sources now**. My memory may be wrong.

Comment: @Mołot check this source  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149799/if-youre-quick-you-can-earn-two-review-points-for-one-review looks like a bug!

Comment: @Bala it has [meta-tag:status-bydesign] so it's not a bug, it's a design choice. No one answered why, not under the one you linked, but I'm pretty sure it's either performance or workload to benefit ratio. Anyway it rather confirms my previous comment, sadly without details.

Comment: @Mołot Actually I'm confused with the bounty offered to the answer and it mentioned It seems like a bug http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149799/if-youre-quick-you-can-earn-two-review-points-for-one-review/149994#149994